# Test-Path returns exception when testing if location exists

Tags: powershell

I am trying to check if a location exists before copying it, using `Test-Path`. As I understand it this should return true or false, depending on if the location exists.

My code

```
if (Test-Path $updatedsource) {
    Copy-Item $updatedsource $record.Target -Recurse -Container -Force
}
```

Instead of true or false, this line is throwing an exception

```
Test-Path : An object at the specified path
\\wnasdce03\SECENV_PROD-01\Users\Results\thorn-01.00rc3\ICEVol_BC_20160715
does not exist
At \\VFIPPFIL005\EMT_Projects\Vimmi\SE\CoypHistoryData.ps1:31 char 22
+ if (Test-Path <<<< $updatedsource) {
    + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (\\wnasdce03\SEC...tC_20160716:String) [Test-Path1. IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemDoesNotExist.Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.TestPathCommand
```

Why am I getting an exception that the location doesn't exist? Surely this should just return false?

Comment: based on the output looks like \wnasdce03\SECENV_PROD-01\Users\Results\thorn-01.00rc3\ICEVol_BC_20160715

wnasdce03 is a computername it should go as \\wnasdce03

Comment: Please do not mangle PowerShell errors. Post them *exactly* as they are. As for your question, going out on a limb I'd suspect that a subfolder was removed during the operation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your erroraction for this command as below:

```
if (Test-Path $updatedsource -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
{
    Copy-Item $updatedsource $record.Target -Recurse -Container -Force
}
```